# "Don't it" instead of "doesn't it'

Tags: grammar, do

Recently I saw a phrase that sounds like that:

> Hurts even with the vest, don't it?

So, the question is: Why there is "don't" instead of "doesn't"?

I've found a lot of usages like that, so it doesn't seem like a grammar mistake.

Comment: It's just a colloquialism. You likely would not use it in formal contexts. *Doesn't* is the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

In the first half of the 19th century, *don't* was the usual contraction for "does not." Since then, *doesn't* has replaced it in the standard language. Today many may feel that *don't* sounds uneducated, but the earlier a person was born, the more likely they are, or were, to use this form habitually.